# More close votes

Tags: feature-request, review

A few people at least ran out of close votes. With the new /review and more reviewing activity, perhaps it is time for a raise?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this would be good or beneficial? The limit is quite generous, and to be honest, I've rarely reached it. If there are a lot of questions that *need* to be closed, I'd rather distribute this among the community – and after all, the limits are in place so you can just take a break, you know :)

Comment: @slhck  With the new /review, it is pretty easy to review 40 questions in 20 minutes, and use up all of one's close votes. If we accept that these votes are good (not users spamming them for no reason) then more of them would also be good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, I'm against that. Not totally, but I'm not sure whether this would be  a good idea.

Your premise is that "all of these votes are good". At the same time, the system would allow you to go through *all* questions that have pending close votes like crazy. Maybe even without properly evaluating them before – just because it's so easy.

While I'm not saying that I don't trust our reviewing users, I think there should be limits. Take flag weight as an example. Gaining flag weight would allow you to have more flags per day, since flags are validated by moderators. (But still, there would be a cap to this.)

Close votes, however, are not validated – and unless we have a good measure that would show how many of your close votes were effective (in the sense of leading to a closed question), you won't be able to say whether a user deserves more close votes or not. Also, it's questionable whether that's even a good measure of which votes are "good" per se.

There really should be limitations, and I'm inclined to say that if you've run out of close votes, better go find something else to do. Work on other stuff. The accusation of a certain "pack mentality" *always* comes up, and allowing users to vote to close more … this is like firing at your target with a machine gun.

I'd say, let's wait until the team has reviewed our `/review` stats generated through the new system and then decides to give us more (or even less) votes.

Comment: Agreed.  There's [checks and balances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers#Checks_and_balances) put in place for a reason.

Comment: Completely 100% agree with this.

Comment: I agree with this sentiment. If you've burned through 40 close votes, I'd recommend going for a walk or answering some questions :P

Comment: I burn through mine once very couple of weeks (or more), but that's me -- and I'm a bit of a jerk who spends too much time on here. ;)

Comment: Tell me 'bout it, @techie007 ;)